# C# - Hiding mouse cursor in program

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mouse-cursor

I have been looking for resource for this issue but could not find what I want. I have a C# application in WPF which uses touch screen with mouse cursor present on the screen for users. The problem is I want to hide this mouse cursor but when I run the program in back end, the application should have mouse cursor displayed.

Does anyone have any good suggestion on where to start?

Comment: Do you use Windows Forms, WPF or some other screen framework?

Comment: WPF application

Answer (score 7):

It's very simple:

```
if(runningAsClient)
    Cursor.Hide();
```

Of course you need a technique to determine the system you're running on, like a preprocessor directive. You can put this in your main method and set the directive in the client project configuration.

```
#if CLIENT
    Cursor.Hide();
```

If you use WPF, you have to set the `Cursor` property of your window to

```
Cursor = Cursors.None;
```

Comment: I mean if the system is ONLINE for real users to use, the cursor should be hidden. If it's offline for us to run the program, for example to enhance the program or fix bugs, it should not be hidden

Comment: Then only set `BACKEND` in the appropriate project configuration (Release Backend for example) and not in Debug. That's why configurations exist.

Comment: Should basically hide cursor in BackEND and that's it?

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood it, of course the cursor should be hidden in the client and not in the backend, but it's same procedure, just change the directive to `CLIENT`.

Comment: Is there another approach? Say I disable it in the app.config file rather than the main application file.

Comment: Yes, You can also use the app.config file just add `<addkey="displayCursor" value="True"/>` to your app.config and are able to read it with `bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["displayCursor"]);`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161793/discussion-between-cookie-monster-and-loris156).

Comment: where do i place the bool.parse?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use command line arguments to achieve this:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Boolean backend = args.Contains("-b");

        // ...

        MyApp app = new MyApp(backend);
        app.Run();
    }
}

public partial class MyApp : Application
{
    public MyApp(Boolean backend)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (backend)
            Cursor = Cursors.None;
    }
}
```

To launch your app as "backend", just use the following command:

```
MyProgram.exe -b
```

and the mouse cursor will be hidden.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but the application is actually run in a touch screen machine.